# "Understanding" the techniques involved in this proof that $F[x, y]/\langle y^2 - x^3 \rangle$ is a domain and is not integrally closed

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, soft-question, examples-counterexamples

Let $A = F[x,y] / \langle y^2 - x^3 \rangle$. In a past exam question (from last year), students were asked to show that $A$ is an integral domain, and also that it is not integrally closed in its field of fractions.

A solution was provided by the university, which I will put in my own words below. The problem is that the ideas involved are quite unfamiliar, and I've never seen a similar strategy employed before. Could anybody give me some examples of similar constructions, susceptible to similar methods?

To be clear, I do understand the solution below; I am happy that each step follows from the last. However, I am not confident that I would be able to come up with such a solution myself in a similar context, and I am looking for more examples, so that I can become more familiar with the ideas.

---

**Solution**

Let $\varphi:F[x, y] \to F[t]$ be the unique homomorphism with $\varphi(x) = t^2$ and $\varphi(y) = t^3$. Then $\varphi(y^2 - x^3) = 0$, so $\varphi$ descends to a ring homomorphism $\bar{\varphi}:A \to F[t]$.

Let $\bar{x}, \bar{y}$ be the images of $x$ and $y$ respectively in $A$. Then $A = F[\bar{x}] \oplus \bar{y}F[\bar{x}]$, where directness of the sum comes from considering degrees. If $f(\bar{x}) + \bar{y}g(\bar{x}) = 0$ then (taking the image under $\bar{\varphi}$) also $f(t^2) + t^3g(t^2) = 0$, which means that $f = g = 0$ since all terms of $f(t^2)$ have even degree and all terms of $t^3g(t^2)$ have odd degree. Therefore $A$ is a domain.

Now, the image of $\bar{\varphi}$ is $F[t^2, t^3, t^4, \ldots]$, and in particular $t \not \in \bar \varphi(A)$. However, taking the natural extension of $\bar \varphi$ to the field of fractions of $A$, we have $\bar \varphi(\bar y/\bar x) = t^3/t^2 = t$, so $\bar y / \bar x \not \in A$. However, $(\bar{y} / \bar x)^2 = \bar y^2 / \bar x^2 = \bar x^3 / \bar x^2 = \bar x$, so $\bar y / \bar x$ is a root of the monic polynomial $X^2 - \bar x \in A[X]$, hence is integral over $A$.

Comment: $A$ is a domain because it embeds into the domain $F[t]$.

Comment: @lhf Right. The argument I've given to show this relies on spotting that $A$ is a graded ring with decomposition $F[\bar x] \oplus \bar y F[\bar x]$, which doesn't seem very general. Are there any theorems or wider classes of examples about embedding quotients like this into domains?

Comment: The image of any ring homomorphism $R \to D$ is a domain if $D$ is a domain. I don't think there's anything more general than that.

Comment: No no I understand that, but doesn't the conclusion that $R$ is a domain rely on the fact that the homomorphism $R \to D$ is injective?

Comment: I didn't say that $R$ is a domain. I said that the *image* of any ring homomorphism from $R$ is a domain.

Comment: @lhf but how does that help? I’m trying to show that $A$ is a domain. In this case the image of the homomorphism is actually isomorphic you $A$, so I agree that the result follows from the fact that $F[t]$ is a domain. It seems like injectivity is the important ingredient?